# mongod won't start on CentOS aws instance

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am trying to start a mongod instance using

```
sudo service mongod start
```

But it simply fails with output:`Starting mongod:                                           [FAILED]`

Any suggestions? I am kinda new to this so maybe this is a really stupid question but I tried everything people suggested and nothing worked

Comment: check mongodb logs

Comment: Where are the logs usually located?

Comment: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making another instance since something was probably wrong with the AWS instance. Any way, this question is irrelevant anymore and probably won't have an answer